# How to use an already trained inceptionV4 model

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow, I use pre-trained inceptionV4 model training my own data
http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v4_2016_09_09.tar.gz

```
python train_image_classifier.py \
--train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
--dataset_name=stamps \
--dataset_split_name=train \
--dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
--model_name=inception_v4 \
--clone_on_cpu=true \
--checkpoint_path=${PRETRAINED_CHECKPOINT_DIR}/inception_v4.ckpt \
--checkpoint_exclude_scopes=InceptionV4/Logits,InceptionV4/AuxLogits \
--trainable_scopes=InceptionV4/Logits,InceptionV4/AuxLogits \
--max_number_of_steps=50 \
--batch_size=32 \
--learning_rate=0.01 \
--learning_rate_decay_type=fixed \
--save_interval_secs=60 \
--save_summaries_secs=60 \
--log_every_n_steps=100 \
--optimizer=rmsprop \
--weight_decay=0.00004

python eval_image_classifier.py \
--checkpoint_path=${TRAIN_DIR} \
--eval_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
--dataset_name=stamps \
--dataset_split_name=validation \
--dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
--model_name=inception_v4 \
--batch_size=32
```

use below code to freeze the graph

```
import os, argparse

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def freeze_graph(model_folder, output_node_names, output_graph):
    # We retrieve our checkpoint fullpath
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_folder)
    input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path

    # We precise the file fullname of our freezed graph
    #absolute_model_folder = "/".join(input_checkpoint.split('/')[:-1])
    #output_graph = absolute_model_folder + "/frozen_model.pb"

    # Before exporting our graph, we need to precise what is our output node
    # This is how TF decides what part of the Graph he has to keep and what part it can dump
    # NOTE: this variable is plural, because you can have multiple output nodes
    output_node_names = output_node_names

    # We clear devices to allow TensorFlow to control on which device it will load operations
    clear_devices = True

    # We import the meta graph and retrieve a Saver
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)

    # We retrieve the protobuf graph definition
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

    # We start a session and restore the graph weights
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)

        # We use a built-in TF helper to export variables to constants
        output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
            input_graph_def, # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
            output_node_names.split(",") # The output node names are used to select the usefull nodes
        ) 

        # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--model_folder", type=str, help="Model folder to export")
    parser.add_argument("--output_node_names", type=str, default="frozen_model.pb", help="output_node_names")
    parser.add_argument("--output_graph", type=str, help="output_graph name")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    freeze_graph(args.model_folder, args.output_node_names, args.output_graph)
```

I don't know which output_node_name to use, now I use `InceptionV4/Logits/Predictions`,

```
python ${OUTPUT_DIR}/freeze.py --model_folder=${TRAIN_DIR} \
--output_node_names=InceptionV4/Logits/Predictions \
--output_graph=${OUTPUT_DIR}/frozen_inception_v4.pb
```

then how to use the output graph `frozen_inception_v4.pb` for image label?

Comment: official [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py) need a input_layer and output_layer, but I dont know which to use for inceptionV4

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the label_image sample code for an example of using a frozen image model:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py

Most of the flags should be ok at their defaults, but you'll need `--input_mean=-127`, `--input_std=127`, `--output_layer=InceptionV4/Logits/Prediction`, and `--graph=${OUTPUT_DIR}/frozen_inception_v4.pb`.

Comment: It looks like the default input layer not found..
`python tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py --image=11323.jpg \
    > --input_mean=-127 --input_std=127 --output_layer=InceptionV4/Logits/Prediction --graph=frozen_inception_v4.pb
    KeyError: "The name 'import/input' refers to an Operation not in the graph."`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to follow the tensorflow doc to retrain inception_v3 here :
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

I couldn't figure out what should be the input_layer in label_image.py but this seemed to work :

https://github.com/Dataweekends/inception-retrain/blob/master/label_image.py